# Calculating large power of a number in c

Tags: c

I am writing a program in c to store 2^100000, and I am using arrays to store the result.
Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int test, n, i, j, x, resul;
    int a[200], m, temp;
    scanf("%d", &test);
    for (i = 0; i < test; i++) {
        a[0] = 3;  // initializes array with only 1 digit, the digit 1.
        m = 1;     // initializes digit counter
        scanf("%d", &n);
        temp = 0;  // Initializes carry variable to 0.
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                x = a[j] * 2 + temp; //x contains the digit by digit product
                a[j] = x % 10; //Contains the digit to store in position j
                temp = x / 10; //Contains the carry value that will be stored on later indexes
            }
            while (temp > 0) { //while loop that will store the carry value on array.
                a[m] = temp % 10;
                temp = temp / 10;
                m++; // increments digit counter
            }
        }
        for (i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) //printing answer
            printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can some one tell me a more efficient way to do so to reduce the time complexity?

Comment: That's only a fraction of the code, post the whole function with the variable definitions and the calling code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integers of unlimited size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649181/integers-of-unlimited-size)

Comment: I have added the whole code as per your request.

Comment: I provided a thorough answer, was it of any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- The array `a` is defined with a size of only `200` digits.  This is much too small for `2^100000` that has `30103` digits.  You should increase the array size and check for overflow in the multiplication algorithm.
- You initialize `a[0] = 3;` and comment this as the digit `1`.  Indeed you should write `a[0] = 1;`.
- The second loop `for (i = 1; i < n; i++)` should include the desired power number:  you should write `for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)`.
- You use the same loop variable for the outer loop and the second level ones, causing incorrect behavior.
- You do not test the return value of `scanf`, causing undefined behavior on invalid input.
- You do not check for overflow, invoking undefined behavior on large values.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, j, x, m, test, temp;
    int a[32000];

    if (scanf("%d", &test) != 1)
        return 1;

    while (test-- > 0) {
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
            break;
        a[0] = 1;  // initializes array with only 1 digit, the number 1.
        m = 1;     // initializes digit counter
        temp = 0;  // Initializes carry variable to 0.
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                x = a[j] * 2 + temp; //x contains the digit by digit product
                a[j] = x % 10; //Contains the digit to store in position j
                temp = x / 10; //Contains the carry value that will be stored on later indexes
            }
            // while loop that will store the carry value on array.
            if (temp > 0) {
                if (m >= (int)(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)))
                    break;
                a[m++] = temp;
                temp = 0;
            }
        }
        if (temp > 0) {
            printf("overflow");
        } else {
            for (i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) //printing answer
                putchar('0' + a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running this code with input `1` and `100000` on my laptop takes about 6,5 seconds.  That's indeed quite inefficient.  Using a few optimization techniques that do not really change the complexity of this simple iterative algorithm still can yield a dramatic performance boost, possibly **100 times faster**.

Here are some ideas:

- store 9 digits per `int` in the array instead of just 1.
- multiply by `2^29` in each iteration instead of just `2`, using `long long` to compute the intermediary result.  Initialize the first step to `1 << (n % 29)` to account for `n` not being a multiple of `29`.  `2^29` is the largest power of `2` less than `10^9`.

Here is version that implements these two ideas:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j, m, test, temp;
    int a[32000];

    if (scanf("%d", &test) != 1)
        return 1;

    while (test-- > 0) {
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
            break;
        i = n % 29;
        n /= 29;
        a[0] = 1 << i;
        m = 1;
        temp = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                long long x = a[j] * (1LL << 29) + temp;
                a[j] = x % 1000000000;
                temp = x / 1000000000;
            }
            if (temp > 0) {
                if (m >= (int)(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)))
                    break;
                a[m++] = temp;
                temp = 0;
            }
        }
        if (temp > 0) {
            printf("overflow");
        } else {
            printf("%d", a[m - 1]);
            for (i = m - 2; i >= 0; i--)
                printf("%09d", a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running it on the same laptop computes the correct result in only 33ms, that's **200 times faster**.

The Time Complexity is the same, but implementation is much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It was very useful. It's the most efficient solution to the problem.

Comment: @AnubhavJain: Could you please upvote and check the answer as accepted so the question is considered solved?

Comment: @AnubhavJain: The accelerated code assumes `int` has at least 32 bits.  Which *code* did you try and found *not working*?

Comment: I tried running the second code storing 2^29 at each iteration, but even for n=50 it overflow.

Comment: @AnubhavJain: indeed there was a mistake in both versions: `temp` must be reset to `0` after storing it to `a[m++]`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

2^n in binary is an (n+1)-digit integer with every bit set to 0 except the most significant bit being set to 1. e.g: 32 = 2^5 = 0b100000

Likewise, 2^100000 can be *computed* by setting the 100001-th bit in a zeroed 100001 bit long integer to 1. O(1) is as time efficient as you can go.

Comment: Sure! but if you want to print it in decimal, is it more efficient to compute it in decimal with a few tricks or to convert the trivial base 2 representation?

Comment: Assuming we're talking about powers of 2 in general, I don't see how it can be printed in decimal without its digits having been computed and stored somewhere, since the digits have to be outputed starting by the most significant one (left to right). I'm not sure though...

Comment: Thanks, but I think converting the binary into decimal will not decrease the time complexity. Or can you tell me a way or two to convert it in decimal efficiently?

Comment: Time complexity is merely a **hint** on how well the algorithm's performance scales with bigger inputs, and two algorithms having equivalent complexities can - and more often than not will - yield different performances. A more *efficient* binary to decimal conversion algorithm would make use of whole bytes/multibyte types to do the computations rather than single base-10 digits. This would at least spare you the `x%10`s. I'll update my answer with a code example as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that native C integers are limited, in practice to some power of two related to the word size of your computer (e.g. typically 32 or 64 bits). Read about `<stdint.h>` and `int32_t` & `int64_t`.

Maybe you want some bignums (or bigints), a.k.a. [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

The underlying algorithms are *very* clever (and *more efficient than the naive ones* you learned in school). So don't try to reinvent them, and use a library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Re-inventing is a very efficient way to learn.  Just like math students learn how to prove theorems, CS students should try and implement algorithms and find out on their own what it takes to write efficient code.  GMP is indeed a good benchmark, and definitely a better option for serious work.  But I believe the OP is working on an assignment or just trying ideas... Have fun and learn!